# Get messages from RabbitMQ on button click

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm trying to consume messages from a RabbitMq queue on button click.
When I put this code in a console app it works but when I am using a button click event it won't work.
I hope you can help me.

This is the server code:

```
public void PushToQueue(Message message)
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "task_queue",
                                 durable: false,
                                 exclusive: false,
                                 autoDelete: false,
                                 arguments: null);

            string messageToSend = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageToSend);

            //var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
            //properties.Persistent = true;

            channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                                 routingKey: "task_queue",
                                 basicProperties: null,
                                 body: body);
            Debug.WriteLine(" [x] Verzonden {0}", messageToSend);
        }
    }
```

This is the client code:

```
public void GetFromQueue()
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "task_queue",
                                 durable: false,
                                 exclusive: false,
                                 autoDelete: false,
                                 arguments: null);

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                Debug.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
            };
            channel.BasicConsume(queue: "task_queue",
                                 autoAck: true,
                                 consumer: consumer);
        }
    }
```

This is te button click code:

```
private void buttonGetFromQueue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rabbitManager.GetFromQueue();
    }
```

I stepped trough the code and it seems that it won't reach this part:

```
var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                Debug.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
```

This is the rabbit manager class:

```
public class RabbitMqManager
{
    public List<Message> allMessages = new List<Message>();
    public RabbitMqManager()
    {

    }

    public void GetFromQueue()
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "task_queue",
                                 durable: false,
                                 exclusive: false,
                                 autoDelete: false,
                                 arguments: null);

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                Debug.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
            };
            channel.BasicConsume(queue: "task_queue",
                                 autoAck: true,
                                 consumer: consumer);
        }
    }

    public List<Message> ReturnAllMessages()
    {
        List<Message> returnList = new List<Message>();

        foreach(Message m in allMessages)
        {
            returnList.Add(m);
        }
        return returnList;
    }
}
```

The messages get pushed to the queue but I can't get them out of it.

Comment: Yes I did step trough the code. I call the GetFromQueue() method in a windows form button click event but it wont reach the following code: var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                Debug.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);

Comment: This is the button code: 
private void buttonGetFromQueue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rabbitManager.GetFromQueue();
        }

Comment: "BasicConsume" is not blocking call, so after subscribing to queue you are immediately unsubscribing (by closing channel and connection).

Comment: @Evk so I should change the BasicConsume to something else?

Comment: You should not close connection\channel until you finished with consuming (now you are closing them because of `using` statements)

Comment: Okay but why does this program work when I put it in a console application? And not when I call the method with an event handler

Comment: Who knows, but probably because you put `Console.ReadKey()` or `ReadLine()` after `BasicPublish`.

Comment: Okay, so I tried a couple of things but I didn't managed to get it work. Do you know how I can fix it? With what should I replace BasicConsume?

Comment: You should not replace it with anything. Only thing you need to do is not closing channel and connection too soon. Create connection and channel in constructor of RabbitMqManager for example, not in GetFromQueue method.

Comment: Allright. Then I will try to do that. I already tried it but I thought it was hard to do that because of the using statements and the 'var' variables.

Answer (score 0):

To Retrive Message from RabbitMQ we need to first connect to the RabbitMQ server:

```
public WebClient GetRabbitMqConnection(string userName, string password)
{
    var client = new WebClient(); 
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
    return client;
}
```

Now retrieve messages from RabbitMQ using:

```
public string GetRabbitMQMessages(string domainName, string port, string 
            queueName, string virtualHost, WebClient client, string 
            methodType)
{
    string messageResult = string.Empty;
    string strUri = "http://" + domainName + ":" + port + 
                    "/api/queues/" + virtualHost + "/";
    var data = client.DownloadString(strUri + queueName + "/");
    var queueInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QueueInfo>(data);
    if (queueInfo == null || queueInfo.messages == 0)
               return string.Empty;
    if (methodType == "POST")
    {
        string postbody = "  
        {\"ackmode\":\"ack_requeue_true\",\"count\":
         \"$totalMessageCount\",\"name\":\"${DomainName}\",
         \"requeue\":\"false\",\"encoding\":\"auto\",\"vhost\" :
         \"${QueueName}\"}";
         postbody = postbody.Replace("$totalMessageCount", 
         queueInfo.messages.ToString()).Replace("${DomainName}", 
         domainName).Replace("${QueueName}", queueName);
         messageResult = client.UploadString(strUri + queueName + 
         "/get", "POST", postbody);
  }
  return messageResult;
```

}

I think this will help you to implement RabbitMQ.